# Is there a way to hide my api in javascript? (pulling it in from php?)

Tags: javascript, php

I have a gaming page that accesses an API that I would like to share but I don't want anyone else using my api. Is there a way to create a variable in javascript that would obfuscate the api? Maybe pull it in from a php page?

Just looking to replace

```
var apiKey = "7**************";
```

so that the api isn't available to people that download the page to use it for themselves.

Comment: If you pull it from a PHP page, the user can just go into the console and look at the AJAX response. If you want to hide the key you need to perform the API call on the server, not from the client.

Comment: If it is in the clientside, no. If you want something to be secure, calls need to be on the server. Even if you "could" hide it, the http requests would be visible in the network panel or any proxy and the credentials could be grabbed that way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide Javascript from your source but you can made it more difficulty to read and understand.
[www.sitepoint.com/hide-jquery-source-code/](https://www.sitepoint.com/hide-jquery-source-code/)

[image]

Image from sitepoint

[Javascript Obfuscate](http://www.danstools.com/javascript-obfuscate/)

Answer (score 1):

No. You cant hide anything in javascript.

No. It's not possible.

Any information that your javascript uses, is public. Any API key that you put in js or pull from server or decode or whatever else can be easily recorded and then used elsewhere.

Create nginx proxy which will just add your secret API key when you make calls to API. But dont share API keys - the only security in this case is lazyness ot your visitors to take that API key.